# Dúvida C++ -solução básica Canto noroeste

Tags: c++

Estou meio esquecido de programação e tenho um algoritmo matemático pra fazer, é o problema do transporte, estou na fase do canto noroeste.

A minha dúvida está num erro de compilação.

Código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int minimo(int valor1,int valor2)
{
    if(valor1<valor2)return valor1;
    else return valor2;
}


int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int matriz[n][m];
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)for(j=0;j<m-1;j++)cin>>matriz[i][j];

    i=0;
    j=0;

    int x,y;
    x=n-1;
    y=m-1;

    while( ((i<=m-2)&&(i<=n-2)) && ((j<=m-2)&&(j<=n-2)) )
    do
{ matriz[i][j]=minimo(matriz[x,j],matriz[i,y]);
if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[x,j]){matriz[x,j]=0;matriz[i,y]-=matriz[i][j];}
if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[i,y]){matriz[i,y]=0;matriz[x,j]-=matriz[i][j];}

if(matriz[x,j]==0)i++;
 if(matriz[i,y]==0)j++;}

    return 0;
}
```

O erro é esse:

> ```
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|28|error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|5|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'int minimo(int, int)' [-fpermissive]|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|28|error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) + -1)) + 1)]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|5|error:   initializing argument 2 of 'int minimo(int, int)' [-fpermissive]|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|29|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|29|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) + -1)) + 1)]'|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|29|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) + -1)) + 1)]'|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|30|error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|30|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) + -1)) + 1)]'|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|30|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) + -1)) + 1)]'|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|39|error: expected 'while' before numeric constant|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|39|error: expected '(' before numeric constant|
> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\transporte.cpp|39|error: expected ')' before ';' token|
> ||=== Build failed: 13 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está referenciando os índices da matriz de forma incorreta, em algumas partes do código. `matriz[x,j]` por exemplo. O correto é `matriz[x][j]`

Outro coisa. Não existe `while (condição) do {}`. O correto é `while (condição) { }` ou `do {} while (condição)`. Levando em conta este erro, e o erro anterior, arrisco a dizer que você está migrando do pascal para o C.

Fiz os reparos na sintaxe do teu código, mas não verifiquei a funcionalidade, pois nem sei o que ele deveria fazer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int minimo(int valor1,int valor2)
{
    if(valor1<valor2)return valor1;
    else return valor2;
}


int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int matriz[n][m];
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)for(j=0;j<m-1;j++)cin>>matriz[i][j];

    i=0;
    j=0;

    int x,y;
    x=n-1;
    y=m-1;

    while( ((i<=m-2)&&(i<=n-2)) && ((j<=m-2)&&(j<=n-2)) ) 
    {
       matriz[i][j]=minimo(matriz[x][j],matriz[i][y]);

        if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[x][j]){
            matriz[x][j]=0;matriz[i][y]-=matriz[i][j];
        }

        if(matriz[i][j]==matriz[i][y]){
            matriz[i][y]=0;matriz[x][j]-=matriz[i][j];
        }

        if(matriz[x][j]==0)
        i++;
        if(matriz[i][y]==0)
        j++;

    }
   return 0;
}
```

Recomendo também que indente o código, pois isso vai facilitar o trabalho de quem for te ajudar.